# handle some errors in Global.asax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, httpexception

I have a web application on .NET4 and MVC3 (razor) .

I want to handle my application errors in Global.asax. I have created application_error function.

I have noticed and found some errors.

one of them returns this string in Application_Error when I am trying to add break point on line  `Response.Clear();` and that error is generic.

how can I find which codes or part of my codes makes it?

my code:

```
protected void Application_Error()
    {
        var exception = Server.GetLastError();
        var httpException = exception as HttpException;
        Response.Clear();
        Server.ClearError();
    }
```

error on httpException:

```
{System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): File does not exist.
  at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.GetFileInfo(String virtualPathWithPathInfo, String 
  physicalPath, HttpResponse response)
  at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext context, String 
  overrideVirtualPath)
  at System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, 
  AsyncCallback callback, Object state) at   
  System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionSt
ep.Execute()
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& 
 completedSynchronously)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution

```
string errorLocation = Request.Path;
```

this syntax in Application_Error() tel you where is the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to state my experience with this exception, in my case the reason was that there was no webpage specified as the start page for the site.